# Colouring a tetrahedron

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

[image]

How would I write down the elements sr and $sr^2$ of G as a product of disjoint cycles?

If I am looking for the orbits of this action, do I have 4 orbits $\{1\:2\:3\}, \{p12\:p23 \:p13\},\{a\:b\:c\},\{pab\:pbc\:pac\}$ correct?

Lets say I am trying to find the stabiliser $G_{(a\:b\:c)}$, why is the stabiliser just G?

I am then trying to find the number of ways to colour the faces using at most 4 colours.Two colours are regarded the if there some element of G that maps one colouring to the other. 
Because there are 8 faces and 4 colours, $|fix(e)|=|x|=4^8$.

Then what I do not understand is, why does $|fix(r)|=4^6$, $|fix(s)|=4^6$, $|fix(rs)|=4^4$ and $|fix(rs^2)|=4^4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Fix(r)=4^6$ because there are $6$ orbits of faces under the subgroup generated by $r$.  More intuitively, to construct a coloring invariant under $r$: $r$ leaves the bottom tetrahedron fixed, so you can color those $4$ faces independently; you can color the top face $(123)$ however you like, and the remaining $3$ faces of the top tetrahedron must be colored the same.  So that's $4^6$ colorings if you have $4$ colors.  $Fix(s)$ must give you the same answer by symmetry.

Similarly, the colorings invariant under $rs$ are those in which the $3$ "side" faces of the top tetrahedron are the same color, and the $3$ side faces of the bottom tetrahedron are the same color; together with the top and bottom faces, that gives $4$ independent choices, so $4^4$ colorings.  $rs^2$ is the same by mirror symmetry.

Comment: By applying a rotation of $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$, where does edge 1 2 map to?

Comment: looks like edge 2 3

Comment: and what about edge a b?

Comment: $r$ doesn't move that edge; $r$ is just rotating the top tetrahedron.  The group is the direct product of two copies of ${\Bbb Z}_3$ acting independently on the two tetrahedra.

Comment: sorry, I meant if s was rotated by $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$ then where would a b be mapped to?

Comment: what's your guess?

Comment: is it mapped to back again to b c because angles of an equilateral triangle add  up to $\frac{2 \pi}{3}$?

Comment: Yes, it's mapped to b c, but not for that reason.  (By the way, the interior angles of any triangle add up to pi).  The $2\pi/3$ refers to the angle of rotation around the center axis.  $2\pi$ is a full rotation, so $2\pi/3$ is 1/3 of the way around.  So the point is that the triangle $abc$ has a rotational symmetry; if you rotate it by $1/3$ of a full rotation, you see that $a\to b$, $b\to c$, and $c\to a$.